# can i use @viewChild to access an element in a different route?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

so lets say I have an element in a different component like navbar component which is always there in all routes ,, navbar has an Icon that Icon has a badge on it which is initially hidden

and when I add something in lets say menu component (which is not a child to the navbar) I want to access that badge element and setStyle with renderer2

How can I do it?

Comment: I would suggest creating a in-memory data service to deal with data and keep in a centralized component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert the navbar component syntax into a parent component and then a router-outlet who calls the other components. Each time something happens in your second component (the one called in router-outlet) you should communicate it with his parent. After this, you let the parent talk to the navbar (who is also a child of the parent).

something like this.

`<parent>
   <navbar></navbar>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </parent>`

Check out this link to see how to communicate between parent and child. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction